# new linked tables MS access

Tags: ms-access-2013

hopefully a simple one but it has me flummoxed. I have a split database where the back end with the data tables reside on a multiuser access server and each user (5 in total) have a front end copy on their own laptops into which they add new data. I have been doing some development work in my own front end copy which has involved new tables which I have kept as local tables so as not to disrupt the work of the rest of the team.

now the issue I have is that I cannot seem to export these new tables to the back end so as to create new linked tables into which the other users can input data.

I have tried opening the back end file and importing them as linked tables but that then treats my own local front end copy as the data source which means others cannot see my data and so on.

I can open each table in turn and export the table and the data but am nervous about subsequently deleting the tables from my local copy as this will involve deleting the relationships. so the first question. Is this the correct way to do it and will the relationships be retained.

I have tried a work around by cutting and pasting the new tables from my local copy into the back end but I then get an error that says relationships must first be deleted.

I am sure there must be a simple way to do this but I am dashed if I can see it. Perhaps I have been looking too long. So my next question is if the export each table on its own is not correct how do I do it?

I am working in MS Access 2013

Many thanks once again for your help and support.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure out a work around and have sorted it. I copied the new tables into a backup of the back end. Deleted everything from the front end and relinked all of the tables old and new to the front end. bit heath robinson but it works